Tire size for replacement
I need to replace tire on an OLD Puch bike. Size is no longer readable. It's on a Rigida rim marked as 28 x 1-3/8 x 1-1/8 700C. What tire size should I order?

Is the existing tyre so old that it doesn't have an ETRTO number on it ?  Thats a two part number in the format xx-yyy or yyy-xx, where xx is the tyre width in mm and yyy is the rim diameter in mm, (aka the Bead Seat Diameter)

It might be worth taking the wheel to a real physical bike shop and getting some in-person help.

Good advice Criggie. I'm a do-it-myself kind of guy but that has its limits!

its more about having ready access to a bunch of different sizes to try right there, instead of ordering on line and waiting for delivery, then possibly having to return and repeat.

I did a search for 28 x 1-3/8 which landed me on this webpage for a tyre where the description says ETRO: 37-642
https://www.bicyclestore.com.au/block-tread-tyre-28-x-1-3-8.html
Another search for ETRO: 37-642 got me to this webpage with a huge table in which it says ETRO: 37-642, INCH 28 x 1 3⁄8, France 700 x 35A
https://www.insportline.eu/advisor/168-how-to-pick-the-correct-tire-and-tube-size
The French sizing (e.g. 700 x 35C) indicates the approximate outside diameter (700mm) and tire width (35mm). The letter at the end gives an indication of the inside diameter of the tyre. In this case, the C stands for 622 mm.
Sheldon Brown's website suggest the same size 700c and if you  measure the inner width of your rim then use the table at the end of Sheldon Brown's webpage then you can confirm the tyre widths that would be a good fit to your wheels. https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html
You will have to remove the tyre from a wheel to measure the inner rim width in millimeters to follow the table.

In summary:


The tyre size/rim width chart represents modern thinking only. 10 years ago we'd expect to mount 54mm wide mtb tyres on 19mm rims. Mavic still gives conservative recommendations different to your table.

28" is a size commonly used in Germany (and other places? but not the UK) to refer to 700c tyres/wheels.
You have pointed out that the rim is helpfully stamped 700c so the tyre bead diameter is not in question.
You can order any 700c tyre that is an appropriate width similar to what is already fitted, which is most likely to be 28mm or 32mm wide (based on similar bikes I have encountered), but you should measure the approx width of the tyre when inflated (or the other tyre) and match with the modern size that seems most appropriate and allows sufficient clearance with the frame.

Noise, interesting reading https://www.renehersecycles.com/myth-18-wide-tires-need-wide-rims/
